# Having problems with If statements in Batch file, RPG game

Tags: batch-file

I'm having a bit of trouble with the handling of an if statement in my Batch RPG. So when you defeat the first wolf in the tutorial battle the flow jumps to :Victory and from there to :LevelUp and that's where it crashes. If it doesn't have the if statement that checks for level it works just fine, problem is it still levels up the character as if the second if statement (the one that checks for playerEXP to be less than 65) wasn't there either.
What mistake am I making with the if statements?

```
    :StartAdventure
    call :PlayerStats
    call :Save
    echo/
    if %sex% == 1 echo His blood boiling with the thirst of adventure, he couldn't wait to get the 
    if %sex% == 2 echo Her blood boiling with the thirst of adventure, she couldn't wait to get the 
    echo chance to enlist in Kovalor's army. The deadliest force in the history of Vinladia.
    pause >nul
    echo/
    echo Meanwhile, %name% had to defend the farm's lifestock from frequent attacks by wolves and other 
    echo vermin.One could see the edge of the woods a few meters away from the tool shed. Everything 
    echo that was used in %name%'s obligations was there.
    pause >nul
    @set checkpoint=1
    call :Save

    :Checkpoint1
    echo/
    echo A wolf approached from the forest, while %name% tilled the carrot patch, its eyes locked on a stray 
    echo sheep. Losing a sheep was as good as losing a month's food. %name% sprung into action.
    pause >nul
    cls
    call :GrayWolf1
    call save%name%.bat
    call :BattleSystemTut
    cls
    echo/
    echo With the wolf dead, %name% was able to rest for the afternoon.
    @set /a playerHP=%playerMAXHP%
    pause >nul

    @set checkpoint=2
    call :Save
    :Checkpoint2
    echo/
    echo Next morning was as boring as any other. Get up, get dressed, feed and water the lifestock and mind
    echo the fields.
    echo Torwards the end of the day, there was sudden movement near the town of Dagoba, which was visible
    echo from the hill %name% always rested on in the evenings.
    pause >nul
    echo/
    echo Screams could be heard and columns of smoke started appearing above the buildings. %name% lived
    if %sex% equ 1 echo alone on his farm. He was becoming afraid of the raiders, whose presense was now obvious, to make 
    if %sex% equ 2 echo alone on her farm. She was becoming afraid of the raiders, whose presense was now obvious, to make
    echo their way up there and loot %name%'s home.
    pause >nul
    echo/
    echo A wolf darted out of the woods, bloodthirsty and mad. It made for %name%.
    pause >nul
    call :GrayWolf1
    call save%name%.bat
    call :BattleSystem1
    cls
    echo/
    echo There was something about the eyes of the wolf that made %name% think that its attack wasn't a
    echo simple matter of being scared, there was fire in his pupils.
    pause >nul
    echo/
    echo %name% decided to investigate a pillar of smoke miles west of Dagoba, but just a few minutes' walk
    echo from %name%'s farm.
    pause >nul

    set checkpoint=3
    call save%name%.bat
    call :Save
    :Checkpoint3
    cls
    echo/
    echo %name% is now at the entrance of the Dagoba Forest.
    goto :ForestEntrance1

    :ForestEntrance1
    echo/
    echo %name% proceeds by...
    echo ----------------------------------------
    echo -----F-Following the path forward-------
    echo ----------------------------------------
    echo -----I-Looking into the Invenory--------
    echo ----------------------------------------
    if %sex% equ 1 echo -----S-Taking a look at his status------
    if %sex% equ 2 echo -----S-Taking a look at her status------
    echo ----------------------------------------
    echo -----M-Menu-----------------------------
    echo ----------------------------------------
    choice.exe /C fism /N
    goto Option%ERRORLEVEL%

    :Option1
    echo %name% walks in a little bit further.
    pause>nul
    goto :Forest1-1

    :Option2
    call :Inventory

    :Option3
    call :ShowStats

    :Option4
    call :PauseMenu

    :Forest1-1
    set checkpoint=4
    call save%name%.bat
    call :Save
    :Checkpoint4
    cls
    echo/
    echo %name% is surrounded by plant life, with the faint sound of animals rustling the bushes and
    echo the smell of smoke in the air.
    goto :Forest1

    :Forest1
    echo/
    echo %name% proceeds by...
    echo ----------------------------------------
    echo -----F-Following the path forward-------
    echo ----------------------------------------
    echo -----B-Backtrack------------------------
    echo ----------------------------------------
    echo -----I-Looking into the Invenory--------
    echo ----------------------------------------
    if %sex% equ 1 echo -----S-Taking a look at his status------
    if %sex% equ 2 echo -----S-Taking a look at her status------
    echo ----------------------------------------
    echo -----M-Menu-----------------------------
    echo ----------------------------------------
    choice.exe /C fbism /N
    goto Option%ERRORLEVEL%

    :Option1
    echo %name% walks further into the forest.
    pause >nul
    goto :Forest1-2

    :Option2
    echo %name% walks back to the entrance of the Dagoba Forest.
    pause>nul
    goto :Checkpoint3

    :Option3
    call :Inventory

    :Option4
    call :ShowStats

    :Option5
    call :PauseMenu

    :Forest1-2
    set checkpoint=5
    call save%name%.bat
    call :Save
    :Checkpoint5
    cls
    echo/
    echo The smell of smoke is getting stronger just like the sounds from the woods. There may be
    echo a creature lurking between the leaves.
    echo The path continues forward. The light from outside the forest is nearly blocked altogether
    echo due to the density of the foliage.
    goto :Forest2

    :Forest2
    echo/
    echo %name% proceeds by...
    echo ----------------------------------------
    echo -----F-Following the path forward-------
    echo ----------------------------------------
    echo -----B-Backtrack------------------------
    echo ----------------------------------------
    echo -----I-Looking into the Invenory--------
    echo ----------------------------------------
    if %sex% equ 1 echo -----S-Taking a look at his status------
    if %sex% equ 2 echo -----S-Taking a look at her status------
    echo ----------------------------------------
    echo -----M-Menu-----------------------------
    echo ----------------------------------------
    choice.exe /C fbism /N
    goto Option%ERRORLEVEL%

    :Option1
    goto :Forest1-3

    :Option2
    goto :Forest1

    :Option3
    call :Inventory

    :Option4
    call :ShowStats

    :Option5
    call :PauseMenu

    :Forest1-3
    set checkpoint=6
    call save%name%.bat
    call :Save
    :Checkpoint6
    cls
    echo/
    echo There is very loud rustling coming from the bushes.
    SET /A randomEnc=%RANDOM% * 3 / 32768 + 1
    if %randomEnc% equ 3(call save.%name%.bat
     call :GrayWolf1
     call :BattleSystem1
    )else(echo The creature appears to have gone away.)
    goto :Forest3

    :Forest3
    echo/
    echo %name% proceeds by...
    echo ----------------------------------------
    echo -----F-Following the path forward-------
    echo ----------------------------------------
    echo -----B-Backtrack------------------------
    echo ----------------------------------------
    echo -----I-Looking into the Invenory--------
    echo ----------------------------------------
    if %sex% equ 1 echo -----S-Taking a look at his status------
    if %sex% equ 2 echo -----S-Taking a look at her status------
    echo ----------------------------------------
    echo -----M-Menu-----------------------------
    echo ----------------------------------------
    choice.exe /C fbism /N
    goto Option%ERRORLEVEL%

    :Option1
    goto :Forest1-4

    :Option2
    goto :Forest2

    :Option3
    call :Inventory

    :Option4
    call :ShowStats

    :Option5
    call :PauseMenu
    ::--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :::::::::::::::Main Game::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :::::::::::::::Player Stats:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ::--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :PlayerStats
    @set playerHP=25
    @set playerMAXHP=25
    @set playerATK=5
    @set playerDEF=0
    @set playerLVL=1
    @set playerEXP=0
    @set playerGLD=10
    @set playerMP=0
    @set playerMAXMP=0
    exit /b
    ::--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :::::::::::::::Player Stats:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :::::::::::::::Show Stats:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ::--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :ShowStats
    cls
    call save%name%.bat
    echo/
    echo Level: %playerLVL% Experience Points: %playerEXP%
    echo HP: %playerHP%/%playerMAXHP%
    echo MP: %playerMP%/%playerMAXMP%
    echo Attack: %playerATK%
    echo Defense: %playerDEF%
    echo Gold: %playerGLD%
    echo/
    echo Press any key to return.
    pause >nul
    goto :Checkpoint%checkpoint%
    ::--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :::::::::::::::Show Stats:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :::::::::::::::Battle System Tutorial:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ::--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :BattleSystemTut
    echo/BATTLE START!
    echo/
    echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    echo :%name% LVL: %playerLVL% Hp: %playerHP%/%playerMAXHP%:----:
    echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    echo/
    echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    echo :%enemy% HP: %enemyHP% :-----------------------:
    echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    echo *TUTORIAL* Here you can see your current HP (hit points) if they deplete, you die.
    pause >nul

    cls
    echo/
    echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    echo :%name% LVL: %playerLVL% Hp: %playerHP%/%playerMAXHP%:----:
    echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    echo/
    echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    echo :%enemy% HP: %enemyHP% :-----------------------:
    echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    echo *TUTORIAL* Your level is also visible here. It's proof of the experiences you've had.
    pause >nul

    cls
    echo/
    echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    echo :%name% LVL: %playerLVL% Hp: %playerHP%/%playerMAXHP%:----:
    echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    echo/
    echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    echo :%enemy% HP: %enemyHP% :-----------------------:
    echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    echo *TUTORIAL* Your enemy's name and HP are also visible.
    pause >nul
    cls
    goto :FightMenuTut

    :FightMenuTut
    echo/
    echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    echo :%name% LVL: %playerLVL% Hp: %playerHP%/%playerMAXHP%:----:
    echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    echo/
    echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    echo :%enemy% HP: %enemyHP% :-----------------------:
    echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    echo/
    echo -------------------
    echo -----F-Fight-------
    echo -------------------
    echo -----S-Spells------
    echo -------------------
    echo -----I-Inventory---
    echo -------------------
    echo -----E-Escape------
    echo -------------------
    echo/
    echo *TUTORIAL* Press the key that corresponds to your choice
    choice.exe /C fsie /N /M "What will you do?"
    goto Option%ERRORLEVEL%

    :Option1
    echo/
    @set /a ATK=playerATK+itemATK
    @set /a DAMG=ATK-enemyDEF
    @set /a enemyHP=enemyHP-DAMG
    echo ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    echo %enemy% received %ATK% damage.
    echo ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    goto :EnemyAttackTut

    :EnemyAttackTut
    SET /A dice=%RANDOM% * %dieRoll% / 32768 + 1
    echo/
    echo XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    if %dice% equ 1 (set /a enemyATK=%dmgattack1% 
    echo %enemy% attacked with %attack1%)

    if %dice% equ 2 (set /a enemyATK=%dmgattack2% 
    echo %enemy% attacked with %attack2%)

    if %dice% equ 3 (set /a enemyATK=%dmgattack3% 
    echo %enemy% attacked with %attack3%)

    if %dice% equ 4 (set /a enemyATK=%dmgattack4% 
    echo %enemy% attacked with %attack4%)

    if %dice% equ 5 (set /a enemyATK=%dmgattack5% 
    echo %enemy% attacked with %attack5%)

    @set /a playerHP=playerHP-enemyATK
    echo %name% received %enemyATK% damage.
    echo XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    if %enemyHP% lss 1 goto :VictoryTut
    if %playerHP% lss 1 goto :GameOver
    goto :FightMenuTut

    :Option2
    echo/
    echo Your magics are not developed enough yet.
    pause >nul
    goto :FightMenuTut

    :Option3
    echo/
    echo You have no items yet.
    pause >nul
    goto :FightMenuTut

    :Option4
    echo/
    echo Escape is not an option now.
    pause >nul
    goto :FightMenuTut

    :VictoryTut
    cls
    echo/
    echo You are victorious!
    echo *TUTORIAL* When you defeat an enemy you gain experience points.
    echo Once you have enough experience you will gain a level, and that increases your
    echo battle capabilities.
    set /a playerEXP=playerEXP+enemyEXP
    set /a playerGLD=playerGLD+enemyGLD
    echo You gain %enemyEXP% experience points.
    echo Your total experience points: %playerEXP%.
    call :Save
    pause >nul
    if %enemyGLD% equ 0 call :LevelUp
    if %enemyGLD% equ 1 (echo %name% found 1 gold piece. 
    call :LevelUp)
    if %enemyGLD% gtr 1 (echo You found %enemyGLD% gold pieces.
    call :LevelUp) 
    ::--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :::::::::::::::Battle System Tutorial:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::::::::::::::Battle System1:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:BattleSystem1
cls
echo/
echo BATTLE START!
goto:FightMenu1

:FightMenu1
echo/
echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
echo :%name% LVL: %playerLVL% Hp: %playerHP%/%playerMAXHP%:----:
echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
echo/
echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
echo :%enemy% HP: %enemyHP% :-----------------------:
echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
echo/
echo -------------------
echo -----F-Fight-------
echo -------------------
echo -----S-Spells------
echo -------------------
echo -----I-Inventory---
echo -------------------
echo -----E-Escape------
echo -------------------
echo/
choice.exe /C fsie /N /M "What will you do?"
goto Option%ERRORLEVEL%

:Option1
echo/
@set /a ATK=playerATK+itemATK
@set /a DAMG=ATK-enemyDEF
@set /a enemyHP=enemyHP-DAMG
echo ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
echo %enemy% received %ATK% damage.
echo ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
goto :EnemyAttack1

:EnemyAttack1
SET /A dice=%RANDOM% * %dieRoll% / 32768 + 1
echo/
echo XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
if %dice% equ 1 (set /a enemyATK=%dmgattack1% 
echo %enemy% attacked with %attack1%)

if %dice% equ 2 (set /a enemyATK=%dmgattack2% 
echo %enemy% attacked with %attack2%)

if %dice% equ 3(SET /A result=%RANDOM% * 2 / 32768 + 1
 if result equ 2 (set /a enemyATK=%dmgattack3% 
echo %enemy% attacked with %attack3%)
)

if %dice% equ 4(SET /A result=%RANDOM% * 3 / 32768 + 1
 if %dice% equ 3 (set /a enemyATK=%dmgattack4% 
echo %enemy% attacked with %attack4%)
)

if %dice% equ 5(SET /A result=%RANDOM% * 4 / 32768 + 1
 if %dice% equ 4 (set /a enemyATK=%dmgattack5% 
echo %enemy% attacked with %attack5%)
)

@set /a playerHP=playerHP-enemyATK
echo %name% received %enemyATK% damage.
echo XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
if %enemyHP% lss 1 goto :Victory
if %playerHP% lss 1 goto :GameOver
goto :FightMenu1

:Option2
echo/
echo Your magics are not developed enough yet.
pause >nul
goto :FightMenu1

:Option3
echo/
echo You have no items yet.
pause >nul
goto :FightMenu1

:Option4
echo/
echo Escape is not an option now.
pause >nul
goto :FightMenu1

:Victory1
cls
echo/
set /a playerEXP=playerEXP+enemyEXP
set /a playerGLD=playerGLD+enemyGLD
call :Save
echo You are victorious!
echo/
echo You gain %enemyEXP% experience points.
echo Your total experience points: %playerEXP%.
pause >nul
if %enemyGLD% equ 0 call :LevelUp
if %enemyGLD% equ 1 (echo %name% found 1 gold piece. 
call :LevelUp)
if %enemyGLD% gtr 1 (echo You found %enemyGLD% gold pieces.
call :LevelUp)
::--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:::::::::::::::Battle System1:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :::::::::::::::Save System::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ::--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :Save
    @echo @ECHO OFF > save%name%.bat
    @echo SET "name=%name%" >> save%name%.bat
    @echo SET "sex=%sex%" >> save%name%.bat
    @echo SET "playerHP=%playerHP%" >> save%name%.bat
    @echo SET "playerMP=%playerMP%" >> save%name%.bat
    @echo SET "playerATK=%playerATK%" >> save%name%.bat
    @echo SET "playerDEF=%playerDEF%" >> save%name%.bat
    @echo SET "playerLVL=%playerLVL%" >> save%name%.bat
    @echo SET "playerEXP=%playerEXP%" >> save%name%.bat
    @echo SET "playerGLD=%playerGLD%" >> save%name%.bat
    @echo SET "checkpoint=%checkpoint%" >> save%name%.bat
    @echo SET "playerMAXHP=%playerMAXHP%" >> save%name%.bat
    @echo SET "playerMAXMP=%playerMAXMP%" >> save%name%.bat
    exit /B
    ::--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :::::::::::::::Save System::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :::::::::::::::Level Up System::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    :LevelUp
    call save%name%.bat

    if !playerLVL! equ 1( 
    if !playerEXP! geq 30 (
    if !playerEXP! lss 65 (echo/
       echo Level Up! You are now level 2!
       echo You gain +3 HP
       echo          +2 ATK
       echo          +1 DEF
       echo/
       set /a playerMAXHP="playerMAXHP+3"
       set /a playerATK="playerATK+2"
       set /a playerDEF="playerDEF+1"
       set /a playerLVL="playerLVL+1"
       pause >nul
       goto :Save)
      )else goto :Save
    )

    if !playerLVL! equ 2(
     if !playerEXP! geq 65( 
      if !playerEXP! lss 115(echo/
      echo Level Up! You are now level 3!
      echo You gain +4 HP
      echo          +1 ATK
      echo          +2 DEF
      echo          +15 MP
      set /a playerMAXHP="playerMAXHP+4"
      set /a playerATK="playerATK+1"
      set /a playerDEF="playerDEF+2"
      set /a playerMAXMP="playerMAXMP+15"
      set /a playerLVL="playerLVL+1"
      pause >nul
      goto :Save)
     ) 
    )else (goto :Save)

    :::::::::::::::Level Up System::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Comment: Please change `)else` to `) else` and add a space before your opening parentheses too!

Comment: Also, your `:LevelUp` section is using **`!`**'s but you haven't enabled delayed expansion, _(and nor do you need to)_. Change them to **`%`**'s.